# discord.py - unexpected keyword argument error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to run a discord bot using discord.py, but every time I do it it spawns to following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/evin/terribot/__main__.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/evin/terribot/__main__.py", line 26, in main
    client.run(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 585, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 463, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 471, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 425, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 750, in parse_guild_create
    guild = self._get_create_guild(data)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 725, in _get_create_guild
    guild._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 297, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 324, in _sync
    self._add_channel(TextChannel(guild=self, data=c, state=self._state))
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 131, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "C:\Users\evin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Running Windows 10, discord.py 1.0.1, Python 3.8. It happens for all of my bots. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Where is the code that caused the error?

Comment: https://github.com/ezliang/terribot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to reinstall discord.py
Latest version of Discord.py is 1.5, so try with that.

Comment: When I update it only updates to discord.py 1.3.3 and it still gives the error. EDIT: works now. Thanks!